# Помощь с зачеркиванием task в todo list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю свой первый todo mini app:)
Хочу что бы на нажатие по таску оно зачеркивалось, но почему-то зачеркиваются вообще все таски.

Реализую следующим образом:

```
  const [todoDone, setTodoDone] = useState(false)

  function handleTodoToggle () {
      !todoDone ? setTodoDone(true) : setTodoDone(false)
       }

  <h3 className={`card__title ${todoDone ? 'card__title-done' : ''}`}
   onClick={handleTodoToggle}>{entry}</h3>
```

Вот так выглядит рендер тасков:

```
        {props.todosCard.map((entry, id) => (
        <li key={id} className='card'>
          <h3
            className={`card__title ${todoDone ? 'card__title-done' : ''}`}
            onClick={handleTodoToggle}
          >
            {entry}
          </h3>
          <button
            className='card__delete'
            onClick={() => {
              props.handleDeleteTodo(entry)
            }}
          >
            <img className='card__img-del' src={del} alt='dellogo'></img>
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
```

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что у вас куча тасков, а стейт один. Покажите, как рендерите таски

Comment: добавил в оригинальное сообщение

Comment: Посмотрите [Компонент с собственным состоянием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474996/1475029#1475029) или в вашем ТУДУ добавьте свойство "выполнено" и аптейтите его, например [обращаясь по индексу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489288/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b5/1489301#1489301)

Comment: что-то я оба примера не могу понять) У меня ведь есть и так у каждого элемента списка свой ключ уникальный, почему стиль применяется ко всем, это из-за того что я стейт один сделал?

Comment: Да. И он применяется ко всем элементам. Добавьте в вашем массиве туту ключ, который будет отвечать за "выполнено" и его меняйте. А при рендере смотрите на этот ключ, а не на переменную состояния компонента

Comment: мозг отказывается понимать(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример, вот так может выглядеть ваш компонет

При клике на кнопку, передаем индекс элемента, на котором произошло событие и по индексу меняем значение ключа status, который отвечает за состояние TODO элемента.

```
const App = () => {

  const [todosCard, setTodosCard] = useState([
    {
      title: "Выучить javaScript",
      status: true
    },
    {
      title: "Выучить react",
      status: true
    }
  ]);

  const handleTodoToggle = (id) => {
    const list = [...todosCard];
    list[id].status = !list[id].status;
    setTodosCard(list);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {todosCard.map((entry, id) => (
        <li key={id} className="card">
          <h3
            className={`card__title ${!entry.status ? "card__title-done" : ""}`}
            onClick={() => handleTodoToggle(id)}
          >
            {entry.title}
          </h3>
        </li>
      ))}
    </>
  );

}
```

Comment: Тестировал в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/line-chart-with-customized-label-forked-gbi2im?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает, но к сожалению теперь не получается добавить новый таск способом который я использовал ранее. setTodosCard([...todosCard, todo]) Таск просто появляется пустой

Comment: setTodosCard([{ title: todo, status: true }, ...todosCard]) при создании таска вот такие параметры использую и работает. Большое спасибо за помощь!